# Subtract 1 year from datetime

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datetime, date, subtraction

I have seen a lot of info on how to subtract one datetime from the other and how to add years on to a datetime. but the following is giving me a headache....

When a user inserts a record a hidden field called subdate with a value of datetime.now is added to the db.

I then need to have an 'old records' page that lists all the entries that are over 1 year old and was hoping to use something (but using subtract method) similar to;

```
(DateTime.Now.AddYears(1))
```

but there is no SubtractYears available? Why?

Please can you let me know how I achieve the same result?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

```
DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1)
```

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addyears.aspx):

> A number of years. The value  parameter can be negative or positive.

Comment: its always the simple things :)

Comment: Believe it: it's simply this. A simple solution for a simple problem... a programmer's dream.

Comment: It also simplifies age checks (though not getting a calculation of age), because you can test for DateTime.Now.AddYears(-18) > birthDate, for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
now = datetime.now()
last_year = (now.year - 1)
datestr = (datetime.strptime(str(now.year - 1), "%Y")).strftime("%y")
print(f"Last Year: {datestr}")
```

The output will be:

Last Year: 20

If you prefer to have four digit year then change %y to %Y